# jquery ui autocomplete custom data (item undefined )

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller

My Script

```
$("#NameSearch").autocomplete({
                                       minLength: 0,
                                       source: function (request, response) {
                                           $.ajax({
                                               url: "/home/universalsearch/" + document.getElementById("filterUniversalSearchList").value + "/" + $("#NameSearch").val(),
                                               type: "POST",
                                               dataType: "json",
                                               data: {
                                                   searchFilter: document.getElementById("filterUniversalSearchList").value,
                                                   term: request.term,
                                               },
                                               success: function (data) {
                                                   response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                                       return { label: item.EmployeeName, id: item.EmployeeID}
                                                   }))
                                               }
                                           });
                                       },     
                                       focus: function (event, ui) {
                                           $("#NameSearch").val(ui.item.label);
                                           return false;
                                       },
                                       select: function (event, ui) {
                                           $("#NameSearch").val(ui.item.label);
                                           return false;
                                       }
                                   })
                                   .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                                       return $("<li>")
                                         .append("<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.id + "</div>")
                                         .appendTo(ul);
                                   };
                               });
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult UniversalSearch(string searchFilter, string searchText)
        {
            var Employees = _home.GetEmployeeDetails(searchFilter, searchText);
            return Json(new { data = Employees }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Problem I'm facing is in autocomplete dropdown I'm getting as undefined.
From controller it return as object array [image: image of data from controller]

I think I made mistake in binding data improperly.
[image: item.EmployeeName and item.EmployeeID] 
dropdown result shows as undefined. 
Is this problem due to jqueru-ui versions ?

Comment: Is your controller receiving the correct parameters?

Comment: @NickG yes check that screenshot it returns data as object array